# Why I'm getting NullReferenceException while trying to refer to Moq Object in unit testing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I have two classes:

- `ProductController` class with `SingleProduct` action
- `Helper` class with its own method `getProduct(ProductsContext db, string id)` which retrieves specified product from database

I'm trying to create unit test for `SingleProduct` action using Moq framework. 
I'm creating mock for `Helper` object, but when test runs I receive `NullReferenceException` for mocked `Helper` object.

What am I doing wrong?

```
[TestMethod]
public void ProductNotFoundTest()
{
    var mockHelper = new Mock<Helper>();
    mockHelper.Setup(h => h.getProduct(It.IsAny<ProductsContext>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(It.IsAny<Product>());

    ProductController controller = new ProductController(mockHelper.Object);

    ViewResult result = controller.SingleProduct("i'm not exist") as ViewResult;
    Assert.AreEqual("~/Views/Product/ProductNotFound.cshtml", result.ViewName);
}
```

---

```
namespace OnlineStoreParser.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private Helper _h;        

        public ProductController(Helper h)
        {
            Helper _h = h;
        }

        public ProductController()
        {
            _h = new Helper();
        }

        public ActionResult SingleProduct(string id)
        {            
            Product product;

            using (var context = new ProductsContext())
            {
                // Find product with specified ID
                product = _h.getProduct(context, id);

                if(product != null)
                {
                    ViewBag.History = product.History;
                    ViewBag.Images = product.Photos;
                    return View(product);
                }                
                else
                {
                    return View("~/Views/Product/ProductNotFound.cshtml");
                }
            }
       }
   }   
}
```

---

```
namespace OnlineStoreParser.Models
{
    public class Helper
    {
        public Helper() { }

        public virtual Product getProduct(ProductsContext db, string id)
        {
            return db.Products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the product controller I see that there is no mock object for the ProductsContext , could that be the reason?

Comment: As I Inderstand I'm creating this object in ProductController constructor and assign it to ProductController's field - _h . Then in SingleProduct action I call getProduct() method  of this object. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Just do it the same way you're doing it with the `Helper` :) All the classes you want to mock you have to set via the constructor like you did with your first constructor.

Comment: that is fine, i am not talking about the helper object. i am talking about the ProductsContext object that you are passing to the _helper object in the SingleProduct method of the controller. That is null.

Comment: agree with @MightyBadaboom you need to mock the ProductsContext object as well in the controller

Comment: @MightyBadaboom So do I need to create ProductsContext object in ProductController constructor?

Comment: `_h` is never assigned because of the local variable in the constructor.

Comment: @Nkosi but ProductController is created so _h is assigned in constructor

Comment: @missbells no it is not. As also mentioned in the provided answer you have `Helper _h = h;` which assigns to a local variable within the constructor. the field `_h` is not assigned in that case. So even though you pass in a mock in the test, the `_h` field was not assigned and as such remained null.

Answer (score 2):

Change your constructor to this.

```
private Helper _h;    
private ProductsContext _productsContext;

public ProductController(Helper h, ProductsContext productsContext)
{
    _h = h;
    _productsContext = productsContext;
}
```

You had two mistakes.

In

```
using (var context = new ProductsContext())
```

you are creating a new `ProductsContext` in your code; even in your test which is bad practice because you don't want to test the dependencies, too.

And in your constructor you're doing

```
public ProductController(Helper h)
{
    Helper _h = h;
}
```

which is not what you want to do. You want to set your variable `_h = h;` and not making a new one (which is not available outside the constructor which means in your method `SingleProduct` your variable `_h` is not set as expected.

Last but not least you should not return `It.IsAny<Product>()` in your mock. Return a new instance. Or for your test just `null`.

Another hint: You're using `ProductsContext` only in your `Helper`. It would be wise to remove it from `ProductController` and add it to your `ProductsContext` in the constructor like I suggested doing it with the `Helper` in `ProductsController` because your `ProductsController` does not need to now the `ProductsContext` at all.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. Your advice is priceless :)

Comment: And I have one more question about using (var context = new ProductsContext()) {}
As I understand I don't need to use this construction anymore and it's enough simple to create new ProductsContext once and to use it for all operations. Am I right?

Comment: Your welcome. Yes, you can create it once and use it for all operations. Thanks for accepting my answer in adavance and good luck

Comment: And also I have question about your hint. Do you mean to move `Helper` to `ProductContext` class and create there the `Helper` instance or to move `ProductContext` to `Helper`? I'm a little confused about it :)

Comment: The second one. Moving the context to the helper because your controller does not need it.